Why does db.get_usable_table_names() not return all tables in my PostgreSQL database using Langchain?
I am following langchain quick start: https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/sql/quickstart/
Below is the code snippit:
import getpass
import os
from langchain_community.utilities import SQLDatabase
from langchain.chains import create_sql_query_chain
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = getpass.getpass()
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("postgresql://xxx:xxx:5432/xxx")
print("db.dialect : ", db.dialect)
print("db.get_usable_table_names() : " , db.get_usable_table_names())

the above is code is working, my issue is for the db.get_usable_table_names() function call, its not returning all the tables from my database.
Do we have any inside what's the reason and how can we ensure we can get all the tables?
